# banach points in different metrics

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

is it possible to have a transformation $T: X \to X$such that there is contraction for T in $(X,d_1)$ but not in $(X,d_2)?$

I tried defining the function $T(x)=x/2$ and $d_1=|x-y|$ but I cannot seem to define a $d_2$ such that T doesn't contract? Is it even possible?

Conceptually I am confused if our existence of fixed point is dependent on the metric?

Comment: Take $d_2$ to be the discrete metric.

Comment: but that gives us q=1/2 (contraction constant) so I don't think it works.

Comment: No. The distance between $\frac x 2$ and $\frac y 2$ in the discrete metric is $1$ whenever $x \neq y$.

Comment: I understand, makes sense! Thank you very much sir

Comment: Next consider the case where the two metrics $d_1, d_2$ define the same topology, but $T$ is a contraction in $d_1$ but not in $d_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $X:=[1,\infty)$ and $f:X \to X$, $f(x)=7\sqrt{x}$.

With respect to $d_1(x,y):=|x-y|$ the function $f$ is not a contraction, but with respect to the equivalent metric $d_2(x,y):=|\ln(x)-\ln(y)|$ we have
$$
d_2(f(x),f(y))=|\ln(7\sqrt{x})-\ln(7\sqrt{y})|=\frac{1}{2}|\ln(x)-\ln(y)|
=\frac{1}{2}d_2(x,y).
$$
The existence of a fixed point is a property of the function.